# Themathic map/choropleth map of the Netherlands

Tags: r, geocoding, geospatial

I have a bunch of data on Dutch individuals that I would like to visualize with a choropleth map. I also have the location of the individuals (longitude and latitude), so I was hoping that it would be possible to visualize that on a Dutch map that is divided into municipalities (="gemeente" in Dutch), so I can color each municipality according to the mean value of all individuals living there. I know that the R package maptools can make choropleth maps, but I believe that it requires template maps in the form of a .shp file. Does anyone know where I could find such a template for the Netherlands? Preferably with municipalities and NOT per province, so for this image it would be the one on the left:

[image]
<sub>(source: [www.kb.nl](http://www.kb.nl/skd/profiel/estads90.gif))</sub>

Any suggestions for other packages/software/etc to do this are also welcome! Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

also try GADM: http://www.gadm.org/
This site is an excellent resource, extra bonus: .Rdata is one of the formats you can download in (containing a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). They also have .shp format, for your case.

Comment: For importing `.shp` files, you can use `rgdal`. Don't forget to check out Spatial taskview http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html.

Answer (score 5):

Your main problem will be finding a shapefile for the municipalities. Once you have that and can easily relate your data at the lat/long level to the municipalities, then plotting becomes easy.

- [ggplot2](http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/2012/02/great-maps-ggplot2/) is a fantastic example.
- [Choropleths in R](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2009/choropleths-in-r/) is a potential example, because it does not use shapefiles, but I believe the maps package supports it
- Failing that, you could always try [Weave](http://oicweave.org)

Answer (score 4):

There are various .shp files for the Netherlands here:

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the maps don't have the municipality borders, but it's a good start!!

Answer (score 3):

You might also be able to find the municipalities layer on [GeoCommons](http://geocommons.com/) and join your data with one of those layers. GeoCommons makes it really easy to make many different choropleth maps quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Another source for shapefiles at Eurostat is [here](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1). However, with a restrictive license, and I believe only at NUTS3 level (I did not look at it, though).

Open Streetmap does contain administrative boundaries,but not as polygons. [Here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Using_OpenStreetMap_data) is a report about how to transform boundaries to polygons. (I did not try)

Answer (score -1):

You can find recent official Dutch maps here: https://www.pdok.nl/nl/producten/pdok-downloads/basis-registratie-kadaster/bestuurlijke-grenzen-actueel in .gml and .xsd formats (not in .shp unfortunately). National borders, province and municipality.